# How can I add one more field to username and password for account creation and authentication in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to register and authenticate users who need more than username and password for authentication because their username is their school registration number and we are enrolling many schools on our platform where registration number may clash and wouldn't be unique anymore except we distinguish it with School Id ...

For instance, when searching for the user within the model instead of using this

```
    var user = UserManager.Find(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

We use

```
    var user = UserManager.Find(model.UserName, model.Password, model.SchooId);
```

Comment: Scott Brady's [Quick and Easy ASP.NET Identity Multitenancy](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy) might be helpful here.

Comment: Hey mate, if the answer below is what you were looking for, please vote up. If not, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new model that inherits from IdentityUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //add more attributes
    public string SchoolID { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: this didnt go bro ... i want to include that SchoolId as a third party argument and make the username not unique since there is a possibility of registering two ...